# non-www to www client side redirection with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I redirect the following url in javascript :

```
http://example.com/?querystrings
```

=>

```
http://www.example.com
```

I want to redirect my url without www to www discarding the querystrings.

I know how to do it server side using mod_rewrite, I am working on a client side js app, where I need this.

Is this type of redirection possible with JS?

My code so far :

```
<body onload="addwww()">
<script>
function addwww() {
 location.href="http://www.example.com";
}
</script>
```

it redirects the entire page to www with redirect loop error. how can I redirect only when there is no www in the url?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried actually checking? `if( location.href.indexOf('www.') < 0) location.href = '...';` would be a very basic example...

Comment: or rather `if( location.href.indexOf('http://www.') == 0)`, if your website has a  `www` anywhere else in the address

Answer (score 3):

This script replace non-www to www:

```
if(!/\.?www./g.test(location.host)) {
    location.href = location.href.replace("://","://www.")
}
```

Comment: This answer is best because 1) if checks only the host, not the path + querystring. 2) It works with http and https.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, you may try something like

```
if (location.href.indexOf('www') < 0)
    location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

or

```
if (!location.href.indexOf('http://www'))
    location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

as a start.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp to identify `www`:

```
if (!(/www/.test(location.href)))
     location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
```